# Set up multiple shipping methods with different table rates?

Tags: magento

I have Magento community edition 1.6.2. I was hoping to set up different shipping methods based on different table rates but dint know how to do it. Can any one help me set up some thing like this?

Ground shipping 
- under 70$ goes with USPS
- if PO box, APO, FPO any value USPS
- 70+ n more UPS Ground
- All order to AK and HI USPS

3 Day shipping 
- Sent with UPS 2 day
- Separate table for AK and HI
- PO box, APO, and FPO no 3 day shipping available

Next day shipping 
- Sent with UPS Red Saver
- PO box, APO, FPO, AK and HI no Next Day shipping available

I also dont know what other back end settings I'll need, like setting UPS/USPS test credentials or any backend Table rates/UPS/USPS settings ?

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sworn to myself not to write any code in or for my own production magento installation. Hence we use extensions for everything we can. The best are the ones with a narrow focus upon install... some will shotgun across the whole app/ filesystem. :P

[Check this extension out](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html)

We're integrating with UPS negotiated rates, so thankfully have stayed away from too much shipping pricing madness.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this extension which does the similar thing. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-tablerates-2664.html . Any one of the extensions serves the purpose, hence thought would be useful for someone. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Free plug to the folks at Web Shop Apps. Their extensions, while at times a little confusing to set up, are fantastic and Karen and her team are very helpful with getting things set up. If you need a shipping solution, check out their catalog, and if you're not sure if it's the right module for you, just ask. Money well spent.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions that expand the limited magento table rates are most of the time the best way to go. I've tried the one here http://tinyurl.com/l5srzrs and worked fine to me.